# Calligraphic numbers

Tags: typography, calligraphy

I want to write the power set of a set S as 2^S. But the 2 should be kind of calligraphic.
I tried cal and mathcal but they do not work with numbers.
Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Could you provide a visual example of what you're trying to accomplish? "Kind of calligraphic" is a pretty vague description...

Comment: Just not a regular 2. And not just italic.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fonts "Zapf Chancery" or its successor "TeX Gyre Chorus" also contain some kind of "calligraphic" digits:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\textcal}[1]{%
  % family qzc: Font TeX Gyre Chorus (package tgchorus)
  % family pzc: Font Zapf Chancery (package chancery)
  \textit{\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont#1}%
}
\begin{document}
  $\mathcal{P}(S) = \textcal{2}^S \qquad
  \text{with }\textcal{2} = \{0,1\}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with TeX Gyre Chorus]

Comment: Minor nit pick, but I think should be `S = {0,1}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill _S_ can be any set. Consider {0,1} as kind of selector that is applied on each element in _S_. Going through all combinations gets all subsets of _S_ and as result the power set.